# Download of Cocoa API documentation

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

Is it possible to download all Cocoa API documentation? I have to work offline a lot of times and sometimes a doubt blocks all my work...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xcode does this for you automatically, unless you've disabled it ?

Your Documentation prefs pane should look something like this:
[image]

Note that in the above case there are 4 documentation sets installed and the remaining uninstalled sets can be installed by hitting the associated `Get` buttons. Once you have the required documentation installed then it's available via the `Help` => `Developer Documentation` menu, even when you are off-line.

Comment: Well, I just do not have access to any documentation when I am offline. I looked at "Xcode preferences > Documentation". There is a list of documentation sets, and there is a "Mac OS X 10.6 Core Library" in it, but it does not provide any offline documentation about Cocoa as far as I've seen.

Answer (score 2):

As @PaulR mentions, Xcode does this automatically.  Look in the Documentation preferences.  If there's no button called "Get" next in the "Mac OS X 10.6 Core Library" row, then it's already downloaded and installed.

If you still don't think it's working, then check out [Ingredients.app](http://fileability.net/ingredients/).  It's an offline documentation browser.  It's pretty nice. :)

Comment: AppKiDo is also great for browsing documentation: http://homepage.mac.com/aglee/downloads/appkido.html

Comment: Although I've solved my problem with Paul R answer, I bet these tools are great for people who does not have a way to connect to the Internet using the development machine in any way. An unlikely problem, I know, but it always happens to me...