# Offline Mac OS X Developer Documentation

Tags: xcode, documentation, osx-leopard

I would like to get all the developer documentation for offline use.
I'm using xcode mostly on my commute and mobile inet is not good enough in my area.
There were a number of questions regarding docs in general answered more or less, but I have a more specific requirement.
At the moment I only have class reference, but i would like to have documents mentioned in "Companion guides" as well. I tried to "Subscribe" to 10.5 Core Library but it doesn't seem to add anything beside the stuff that was installed with XCode. I'm using XCode 3.1.2 if that makes any difference.
What options do i have? Downloading officially/wget'ing everything/finding some obvious button in preferences?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Dash.app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dash/id458034879?ls=1&mt=12) is a great documentation viewer that has all of Apple's docs for offline viewing (as well as tons of other frameworks/languages).

Comment: Dash is great!!! If you like it, **there is currently a giveaway** at http://blog.tinned-software.net/giveaway-dash-offline-access-to-documentation/

Comment: It has a paid option, but gives you the same functionality for free with a nag. I would guess the assumption is, developers should want to support developers.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though XCode should be downloading it if setup as per this question:

[Download of Cocoa API documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174024/download-of-cocoa-api-documentation)

Comment: I tried the forementioned approach but to no avail. Whenever I click to any of companion guides I'm routed to something like http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003290 it starts Safari and goes to apple.com.