# Is there a way to have XCode ask before downloading documentation/API updates?

Tags: xcode, xcode4

By default, XCode is setup to download updates associated with the various documentation and API libraries available to the application.  This [can be disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5174024/download-of-cocoa-api-documentation) from the XCode preferences screen.  However, I'd prefer not to disable the automatic updates but, rather, prompt me to start the updates so that I can potentially dismiss them for download at a later time.

My reasoning is because I primarily work through a network connection that gains access to the internet through a 4G wireless hotspot that gets hit by overage fees.  In fact, I'm connected through this device, to the internet, about 90% of the time I'm working on my Mac.  When I need to download any form of large software update, I always take my Macbook to an open, direct-connect source to the internet and let it do what it needs to do.

This works fine for most software, but not XCode.

I want my updates to remain automatic (so that I am at least informed that there is an update available,) however, I'd like to have the choice whether to initiate them or not.

Is there something that I can do to make XCode ask before downloading?

**A QUICK NOTE**

I know how we technical minded folk are-- half of you are still wondering why I work off of a 4G hotspot and want to fix that problem, instead of the one I asked.  (Yes, I tend to think this way too.)

However, I work in an environment that has an IT department that adamantly refuses to allow any operating systems, other than Win XP and Win 7, onto their network.  The Engineering team (which I work for) has to have an internet connection and an internal network for storing and backing up data and we are developing iOS software that is integrated with our products. This is obviously problematic since we need to use Macbooks to do our work.

Our solution to this dilemma has been to setup our own, small LAN and our only way of getting internet access is through cellular WiFi.  All WiFi ISP plans that are available in our region are tier-based and overages are charged (at a reasonable rate) when we use more than our allotment of data.  We don't mind going over our quota, however, we need to keep it reasonable.  Automatic updates like this can start to take a huge hit on our network when a few of us have to download a few GBs of data each month.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Software like [LittleSnitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) might be the best solution (firewall).
In case Xcode tries to update itself, the dialog below shown.
Now you can simply `Allow` or `Deny` the connection.
This way you can accurately control all connections (and your privacy).
Other applications might also consume quite some bandwidth.

[image: LittleSnitch]

P.S.
*Why not connect a cheap XP box to the network,

which shares the internet connection to all Macs?*

Comment: RE, your PS.  That is, actually, what we do.  We have a Mac Mini, that is a firewall running Windows Server 2008.  However, our internet is still through the 4G network, because connecting a Mac PC, to a Windows machine, that is on the corporate network is still disallowed.  I have to watch what I say on sites like this, but let's just say this has been a case of some people not being able to see past the ends of their noses.  We could ignore IT's mandates but we aren't really looking to instigate a (much needed) IT revolution-- we just want to get our work done.